# Tooltip onTap rather than onLongPress possible?

Tags: flutter

there's no named parameters to configure a single tap to trigger Tooltip,

my feeling about the default longPress interaction is that users cannot find this deep-buried function.

I tried to find some hint in [tooltip source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/tooltip.dart) but failed.

```
 Tooltip(
   message: 'this is something',
   child: SizedBox(...),
 )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way is to use:

```
triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap
```

Here's an example:

```
Tooltip(
  triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap,
  message: 'this is something',
  child: SizedBox(...),
)
```

Comment: Finally. Great.
This feature was added recently with this merge https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/84434

Answer (score 13):

First, define globalkey: `GlobalKey _toolTipKey = GlobalKey();`
Then wrap your tooltip:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    final dynamic _toolTip = _toolTipKey.currentState;
    _toolTip.ensureTooltipVisible();
  },
  child: Tooltip(
    key: _toolTipKey,
    message: "Your message",
    child: Icon(
        Icons.info,
      ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get a functionality you need is to clone the original Tooltip widget (call it e.g. TooltipCustom) and change inner `GestureDetector` behavior.

Particularly replace `onLongPress` to `onTap`:

```
class TooltipCustom extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Creates a tooltip.
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    Widget result = GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: _handleLongPress,
      excludeFromSemantics: true,
      child: Semantics(
        label: excludeFromSemantics ? null : widget.message,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
    ...
    return result;
  }
}
```

P.S. It's possible to lose a tooltip hiding feature. Take a look at `_handlePointerEvent(PointerEvent event)` handler function and realize a proper call of `_hideTooltip()` method.

Comment: That's definitely not a good solution. The default `Tooltip` widget position the tooltip box given the available space. In you example you just ignore that the tooltip may get covered by the available scroll area.

Comment: Nope. This solution just repeats original code in 99% and gives full control on functional. The only downside is duplication of existed official code.